# Unable to install application

Tags: vb.net, version, installation, .net-assembly

I have two applications in VB.NET. When I was implementing second project I just copy & paste first one and made some changes because they are similar. In each solution I have also setup project for installation. Now when I want to install second application with setup, I can't because I get this message:

> Unable to install because newer version of this product is already installed.

So I have two independent applications (each has different version number, title, product name). The same attributes are only Company, Copyright and Trademark. But to OS it looks like these two applications are the same but only different versions.

My question is how can I distinguish these applications to look like different independent applications? What attribute during installation is important to find out if this application is already installed? Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick guess - you may want to check that the two projects don't have the same GUID (you'll probably need to open the project files in a text editor to check this).

I don't know for sure if the installer package checks this, but definitely a potential candidate for causing this behaviour.

Comment: You are right, probably this causes this problem. But I thought that GUID is automatically generated. So I have to manually change GUID? Are there any rules how  to do that?

Comment: It is automatic, but you said you copied and pasted the code - I assumed that meant the project files too? It's only generated when you do `New Project...`

Comment: To be honest, I would just create the projects from new, and then copy all the files back into them and `Include in Project`, that way you can be sure nothing is messed up in the proj files or references.

Comment: That is true. Next time I will do that like you said. But now would be much easier to create new empty project, copy its GUID, paste it into my project and delete the new empty project. In this case I can be sure that GUID is unique.

Comment: Yeah, check the source control sections as well (if you are using source control) - project GUIDs get randomly copied into those iirc. Good luck - hope this solves the issue.

Comment: Check inside the installed project (with a text editor) then - perhaps duplicate `ProductCode` or `PackageCode` is the problem?